# Attempting to mount multiple shares to the same server results in an error

Tags: delphi

I am writing a service which mounts one or more shares on a server at startup.  when I start it with multiple shares configured I get the error "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed".  I realise that this is an OS limitation however explorer can and does allow multiple shares to be mounted onto the same server, what techniques does it use to do it?

Comment: The error is clear you have already a share on the same server using a different username to connect. Under which credentials does your service run?

Comment: All shares to the same server in a given context/session need to be mapped by the same user using the same credentials.  If you're doing this from a service your shares won't be visible to the logged-in user unless you map them in the logged-in user's context (which you can't do at startup because the user isn't yet logged in). A service isn't the way to do this unless the shares are only needed by the service itself (and not any users). You can squeeze one more credential out of this by mapping one share by UNC path (\\ServerName\...) and another by IP address (\\10.1...) but that's about it.

Comment: @J.. - I don't think logging in is required to be able to use user credentials.

Comment: Did you try one of the two workarounds mentioned in the [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938120)?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz If we mean mapped drives then I think they only persist in the user's session - you can't map a drive to a user session that isn't active.  Not sure if there's a way to add the entries to a user's `HKLMACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` path with API calls?  These only get mapped after the user logs in, though.  Don't need a service for that in any case.  Usually I've always managed mapped shares with login batch files through AD.

Comment: @J.. - That's Ok. It's not clear from the question that the mapped drive should also be available to the user's interactive session, if that's the case then a service with explicit user credentials will not work. If that's not required, the service will create its own logon session with user credentials and be able to use the mapped drive itself.

Comment: Sertac and J...  Thanks for your replies.  The service mounts the shares only for its own use not other users.  I will have to do the mounting via address not the server name so I will do some testing.  The service currently mounts one share ok the problem was mounting more. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Sertac - Yes I tried using the ip address of the share and that looks like a usable workaround.  I used GetAddrInfoW() to convert the share name into and address and substituted that into the share mounting string.  Thanks